# Add line break after every 20 characters and save result as a new string

Tags: python

I have a string variable `input = "A very very long string from user input"`, how can I loop through the string and add a line break `\n` after 20 characters then save the formatted string in a variable `new_input`?

So far am only able to get the first 20 characters as such `input[0:20]` but how do you do this through the entire string and add line breaks at that point?

Comment: What code have you tried? What's wrong with the output you're currently getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this

```py
inp = "A very very long string from user input"
new_input = ""
for i, letter in enumerate(inp):
    if i % 20 == 0:
        new_input += '\n'
    new_input += letter

# this is just because at the beginning too a `\n` character gets added
new_input = new_input[1:]
```

Answer (score 6):

Besides the `list comprehension` + `join` approach (which is pretty convenient btw), you can also use python bulit-in [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
'\n'.join(re.findall('.{1,20}', string))
```

To make it general to every `nth` character:

```
n = 20
'\n'.join(re.findall('.{1,%i}' % n, string))
```

As @CrazyChuck correctly supposed, this can take a bit longer than the list comprehension approach. For example, given a string with 1 billion characters (e.g. `string = 'A' * 10**9`), it took me 10.6 seconds with `list comprehension` and 12.6 seconds with the `regex` approach. Maybe there's a big difference for even larger strings, but it's not a problem for no so large strings.

Comment: Man... I know that will probably take longer to run (kinda want to test that now), but it's so nice and concise! Very readable intent, too. Only problem is that it omits any remaining characters left at the end. Do you know if there's a way to get the last bit with this approach?

Comment: @CrazyChucky, you're right! I've updated the answer, I think it's working properly now.

Comment: Nice! I've never actually used repetition ranges like that before. It's not often that I see an answer on SO that becomes my new favorite idiom for something so fundamental. This is so readable that next time I need to split up a string, unless I'm optimizing a bottleneck, I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than step through each character individually, you can access slices of the right length.

```py
text = "A very very long string from user input"

line_length = 5
lines = []
for i in range(0, len(text), line_length):
    lines.append(text[i:i+line_length] + '\n')
print(''.join(lines))
```

You could replace the `for` loop with a list comprehension instead:

```py
text = "A very very long string from user input"

line_length = 5
lines = [text[i:i+line_length] + '\n' for i in range(0, len(text), line_length)]
print(''.join(lines))
```

Prints:

```
A ver
y ver
y lon
g str
ing f
rom u
ser i
nput
```

Change `line_length` to `20` for your actual, longer input.

Note: a literal reading of your question would omit the final newline (`'\n'`) if the final line has fewer than 20 characters. You can do so if you wish, but if you're going to be printing this to the screen or saving to a file, you probably want the final line to have a newline, even if it's a shorter remainder.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you need to split a string for every nth character.

Then you can just use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
This will get you the list of strings and you can simply join it with the [`join` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).
Like this:

```
some_str: str = "A very very long string from user input"
n: int = 20
splitted_str: List[str] = [some_str[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(some_str), n)]
result: str = "\n".join(splitted_str)
```

Comment: If you're using `'\n'.join()`, you probably want to add a final `'\n'` at the end too.

Comment: In the question, there's this condition " add a line break \n after 20 characters". To be perfectly formal we need to check that the last splitter string has 20 characters and only then add a `\n`.
Anyway, it's not clear do we need it or not.

Comment: Good point, that is true. Probably a good idea to encourage ending all lines with newlines, though.

Comment: Upvoted both of your approaches! In any case, just adding `+ '\n'` should work here (if that's the case. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic and spelled out way of adding a new line for every 20 chars.

```
user_input = "A very very long string from user input" #1
char_count = 0 #2
new_input_list = [] #3
user_new_input = '' #4
for c in user_input: #5 
        char_count += 1 #6 
        new_input_list.append(c) #7 
        if char_count == 20: #8 
            new_input_list.append('\n') #9 
            char_count = 0 #10 
print(user_new_input.join(new_input_list)) #11 

#1 user_input can't use input because that is a reserved word in python 
#2 used to keep track of number of chars looped through
#3 list to append the chars looped through and the '\n' (new line)
#4 used to hold the joining of the chars and new line in new_input_list
#5 for loop to loop through the user_input string
#6 counts the number of chars by counting the number of loops
#7 appends chars to list
#8 enter condition that once 20 loops(chars) have passed
#9 appends new line to list
#10 resets the char_count to 0 so condition can be used on the next 20 chars
#11 prints out the joined list to a string called user_new_input
```